# Calendar Pop Up - Extend year range

Tags: views, search, datetime

A little bit of introduction:
I have a specific content type with the name "Database" where i can add content and with the views module and Search API, the user is able to search on my site for that content.

When I was creating the fields for the content type i noticed there were no fields for "date". So I installed Date module that allows me to have a **Popup Calendar**. On "MORE SETTINGS AND VALUES" i managed to extend the year range for 10 years. So, when i am adding content i'm able to choose from 2004 to 2022. So far so good!

In the view I created, i added some filters to make it easy for the users to search in the database. One of them is "Search by date" and I was able to display the same popup Calendar. 
**My problem is**: the year range is not the same. It is only 2011 - 2017 and i have no idea how to change that. Since is the same from the previous configuration it should work...

Sorry for the confusing explanation, i don't know how else to put this.

Hope you guys can help me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The "Search by Date" Views field should be configuration (clickable) in the Views Administration and in its settings allow you to select the Year range, or the granularity of the date fields and their format.

Comment: I can't find any options. All i manage to do is select if I want Popup  or custom.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

I don't know if it is the right way to do it.

I changed line 329 of the data_popup.module file and replaced the "year_range" to this: $year_range = '-10:+10';

At least is working!

But, if you have any other suggestions please feel free to give them.

Thank you :)